# Call a function/event or pass data to Website(C#) whenever value of variable changed in Web-service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, windows

I have one windows application which is listening to **events** of a device attached(on USB port) and passing event name to web service(**In Real Time**).
And I have a website on which I want to perform certain operations according to the **event  of device(In Real Time)**.

So I want to pass data or call function on website whenever a new **event value** is passed from windows application.

I tried to use **timer** on web page which is calling Web-service to get latest value. But the problem is that events are changing very rapidly.

*Is there any way that web-service automatically send some data to my website? or any other solution.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever used Node.js? That's likely going to be your answer but keep in mind somebody isn't going to be able to provide an entire solution for you on this forum - you'll need to take that back and get started and then ask questions about very specific functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will definitely search about Node.js. I don't expect entire solution, just want to know if I am on right track or if there is other better way.

Answer (score 0):

With the best of my knowledge, I think you cannot just directly pass the data on your website from the web service, since the service itself doesn't know to which it is connected with.

For your scenario what I will do is, make a database with some required tables in it and store the data in there from a web method whenever it is called by your windows application, since your application is entirely built on .NET you can simply pass the DataTable object without having to parse the XML data on the other side. Now, make a web method that will return this data from the database. Call this web method from your website. When the data has been sent to the website, you can however delete it from the database so that the new data can then be sent in the next call.

It might help you!

Comment: Thank for reply. I got the basic idea. But the last part is not clear to me "Now, make a web method that will return this data from the database". If I make method to read data from database, isn't it the same way.. that I have to call web method again and again to get latest data? The problem is I don't know when new value goes into database.

Comment: What do you mean by calling the web method again and again to get the latest data? Anyhow, making a web method that will return the data as DataTable will certainly help you. When your windows application calls the web method for a data change, insert this data in the database. And, when this data has been sent to the website, delete that. One approach!

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Let me clarify _The events of device are continuously changing and I have to respond on website according to current Event in the real time._ Thanks

Comment: Ahan, real time transferring is a bit different approach. By the way, you didn't mention this thing in the question :|

Comment: Sorry about that. May be I edit my question. Do you know any approach to listen to real time events?

Comment: You might have to send ajax calls on the website, not sure though.