# How to listen device events in ASP .net website (In real time)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows

Is there any way by which I can listen to **events** fired by device *(Speech mike, Kind of dicta phone)* attached to *client's computer* in my **ASP .net website**?

I need to listen to *real time events* of device *(Speech mike, Kind of Dictaphone)* and the frequency of event firing is very high.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think it's done by installing an activex control...i am not too sure about that...

Comment: Ok.. I will look into it.. if there is any possibility.

Comment: also, which events are you trying to listen to? some events only come to UI applications that have the message pump. For example, user login/log out, etc.

Comment: I am trying to listen to events fired by a speech mike(kind of Dictaphone) attached to client's computer.

Answer (score 2):

No, asp.net runs on a remote webserver and there's no way it could listen to a client's HW events. You can't even access user's files and folders, because it would be a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not have the native capability to listen to a device's custom events. Software would have to be loaded at the client side to report the events to a webservice.

Comment: I tried that approach also([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201877/call-a-function-event-or-pass-data-to-websitec-whenever-value-of-variable-cha)). But the problem is .. events are fired too frequently. And I have to respond in real time on my website. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot listen to machine events from your web application because it runs on server. You should try some kind of plugin to do this job, like a Silverlight App for example!